# django ViewDoesNotExist

Tags: django

I'm getting a weird error and I can't track it down.  The stack trace doesn't give any clue as to the location of the error either.  It's just giving me the standard urlresolvers.py ViewDoesNotExist exception.  Here is the error message:

```
Could not import myapp.myview.views. Error was: No module named model
```

At first I thought I forgot to put an "s" on models somewhere in my code, but after a search of the entire codebase, that is not the case.

Here's the trackback:

```
File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  91.                         request.path_info)
File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  216.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  216.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  216.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  123.             return self.callback, args, kwargs
File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _get_callback
  132.             raise ViewDoesNotExist("Could not import %s. Error was: %s" % (mod_name, str(e)))

Exception Value: Could not import myapp.myview.views. Error was: No module named model
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From what you've posted, it seems like the error is in myapp.myview.views.

You already mentioned looking for misspellings of "models", which is good. You might also try asking Django to validate your models to ensure that they are properly importable (run this in your Django project root):

```
python manage.py validate
```

Beyond that, just keep following the imports in myapp.myview.views until you see something odd. You can check to see if everything is properly importable by opening a shell:

```
python manage.py shell
```

And attempting to import and/or try things from there.

Beyond that, someone may be able to assist you more if you post the full traceback. Good luck!

Comment: The error was in an import in a total other app.  Using the shell to import things one at a time worked.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I have been having the same error, and I solved my problem. If you have a forms.py, ensure that all your forms fields are valid. For some reason, if your forms.py file has form field errors, then it causes this exception.

Answer (score 0):

So `myapp/myview/views.py` imports `model` and fails. What does the import statement look like?

Comment: @khateeb: It's been two years now, but I am pretty sure I was asking about the import statement in `views` and not how to import `myapp.myview.views`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if everything is properly importable by opening a shell:

```
python manage.py shell
```

That creates a running environment just as the same as where there is request and response. I believe you can get light on this question if you do it, because I have ever got it and managed it.

Good luck with you.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the view that couldn't be imported had a bad decorator call. Try commenting out the decorator.

```
#@login_required(login_url=reverse('bad!'))
def view_name(request):
```

Specifically the reverse is failing. Changing it to

```
@login_required(login_url='http://usatoday.com')
def view_name(request):
```

works. But, strangely enough, this one url doesn't work:

```
@login_required(login_url='http://foxnews.com')
def view_name(request):
```

(yes that's a joke)

I just discovered I should be using [`reverse_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse_lazy), so this is the ultimate solution:

```
@login_required(login_url=reverse_lazy('bad!'))
def view_name(request):
```

Strange this would cause a `ViewDoesNotExist` error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error:

It was urls.py of the app.

I forgot to add '' in the starting of urlpatterns

**SOLUTION**:

**just add '', to the urlpatterns**
    from django.conf.urls import patterns,include,url

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^profile<url name>/$','userprofile.views.user_profile<location of view>'),
)
```